# How to use WCF functions in REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, visual-studio-2013

I am new to WCF services and I have made one. It has 8 functions and I tested them in client desktop app, all work fine. My main task is to use those functions in REST service. I passed a tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

and I understand what I need to do, but I don't know how to start, because I don't know which type of project to use and how to make it work. Besides the fact that I need to make this REST service, I didn't get any further instruction.

So, if anyone has an idea or any tip, I would be thankful.

Comment: Try to find some articles about RESTfull services. The fact you want to use WebAPI doesn't make it a RESTfull service, and the fact you have it working in WCF doesn't mean it is a RESTless service.

Comment: After some Googling around: `Alas, you have been using REST, building REST services and you didn't even know it` http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your answer. I read some articles, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx but I am still stuck and that is way I wrote here. My functions are simple, I am getting some data from db(SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDateReaded) and of course I just need to show them with REST. REST is working with noungs, objects, resources and operating  with HTTP methods.As I see it, it can be more or less a simple web app project but if I am going to use our functions I need to implement the code and then to do it with "rest coding"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may below artical would be help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: I found yesterday exactly that article and use it and it works. Thanks for your answer.